# Display y-axis for both ends of faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have four plots that I combine using facet_grid(). Is it possible to display the y-axis both for the left and the right end of the plots?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981416/dual-y-axis-in-ggplot2-for-multiple-panel-figure) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another) question.

Comment: @Jaap Those question deal with dual y axes (one of which might be plotted on the right side). This question is more about just showing the same axis on the right side for facets, and as such http://stackoverflow.com/q/6625691/892313 is closer to a duplicate (though that question is about showing the axis _only_ on the right rather than _also_ on the right).